# Failed to load build/toastr.min.css in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the toastr api in my angular app. But it won't load.

I've used npm install --save toastr to import the library.

Page Component

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private backend:WebsiteBackendService,private toastr:ToastrService) {
    this.mouseOverSubmit = false;
   }

  submit(formValues) {
    this.toastr.success("Form Submitted!");
    this.backend.submitBlogArticle(this.form.getRawValue()).subscribe((data:any) => {
      //this is where a response would come in
      console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(this.form.getRawValue());
  }
```

Angular.Json

```
 "styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
 ]
```

App.Module

```
  providers: [
    ResolveService,
    ToastrService
  ],
```

toastr service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

declare let toastr:any;
@Injectable()
export class ToastrService {
    success(message:String,title?:string) {
        toastr.success(message,title);
    }
}
```

I've made edits according to what I've seen in the comments below but the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

angular.json file

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css" // <-- remove it
 ]
```

Remove this line from `scripts` section as it is not a script. You made a mistake and added it to both: styles and scripts. According to the [docs][1], the only change to the `angular.json` file should look like this:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add toastr.min.**js** instead of toastr.min.**css** in the "scripts" section of angular.json.

Also, you don't need to add the toastr links in the html itself, as it would be available from the angular.json file.